# Problem not running Sift software in Rstudio

Tags: r, sift

I want to run the `SIFT` software in R, but when I start, the message `Error in the library: there is no package called ‘reshape2’` is displayed in R Studio. What is the problem?

Comment: Just install the package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that the package "reshape2" has not been installed. You can install it with

```
install.packages('reshape2')
```

Comment: I installed this package but the problem was not solved. You can explain more about installing this package? Could the problem be something else?